# Invalid magic number when attempting to boot from a bootable USB flash drive

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I want to install Linux on my laptop, and I follow the instructions on Google "How to make dual bootable Linux and Windows"

I have download Linux Mint (Rufus)

But when I try to boot the USB flash drive , I get this error:

```
Error: Invalid magic number
Error: You need load kernel first
```

What I can to fix the problem?

Comment: What are the boot settings in the BIOS? Have you tried using a different USB drive?

Answer (score -3):

Check your USB key (probably erase and create a new fresh boot USB software).
Based on my experience and external fonts ([linux question](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/invalid-magic-number-when-creating-a-mint-19-2-usb-boot-4175663574/)) the USB is corrupted.

As suggested, I quote the external font:

> 11-13-2019  "I tried a different port, same thing, then I recreated the USB key using a different key (larger size as a matter of fact...) and BINGO! It works."

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.